# How should i attempt to change links in a aspx webform without going into the html

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have this code that works fine but what i want is for the links to be changeable without needing to go into the html level. Probably something like a vb.net form with a textbox and upon button click the link replaces the one i currently have.

Is it possible to link vb.net windows form with aspx.net form? If yes, what is the optimal way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step=1
var whichimage=1
function slideit(){
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
whichimage=step
if (step<3)
step++
else
step=1
setTimeout("slideit()",1800)
}
slideit()
function slidelink(){
if (whichimage==1)
window.location="http://www.google.com"
else if (whichimage==2)
window.location= "http://www.facebook.com"
else if (whichimage==3)
window.location="http://www.twitter.com"
}
//-->

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Suppose the textbox is this

```
<input id="txtbx" type="text">
```

then you can get the textbox conatins like this

```
function slidelink(){
if (whichimage==1)
window.location= document.getElementById('txtbx').value;
else if (whichimage==2)
window.location= document.getElementById('txtbx').value;
else if (whichimage==3)
window.location= document.getElementById('txtbx').value;
}
```

Comment: That only works if the code is on the same form right? Suppose i have 1 form for input and another for output. How should i link them then?

Comment: @user2767437 - You can use asp.net state management techniques for this

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier if i had a windowsform with textboxes where i input the values(links) i want? Then replace the link of the code above using response redirect. Or would that be more troublesome?